# How to change index of Json use Http. in Angular 4?

Tags: arrays, json, angular, angular4-httpclient

I have json in [mockapi](http://5a2144503fd2f10012d78779.mockapi.io/container) like

```
[{"id":"1","name":"Container 1","widgets":[],{"id":"2","name":"Container 2","widgets":[]},{"id":"3","name":"Container 3","widgets":[]}]
```

and I want to make it like:

```
[{"id":"2","name":"Container 2","renamed":"true","widgets":[]},{"id":"1","name":"Container 1","renamed":"true","widgets":[]},{"id":"3","name":"Container 3","renamed":"true","widgets":[]}]
```

I tried clear json (loop delete) and post json above and the result is:

```
[{"0":{"id":"2","name":"Container 2","renamed":"true","widgets":[]},"1":{"id":"1","name":"Container 1","renamed":"true","widgets":[]},"2":{"id":"3","name":"Container 3","renamed":"true","widgets":[]},"id":"4","widgets":[],"renamed":"true"}]
```

But I want exactly like:

```
[{"id":"2","name":"Container 2","renamed":"true","widgets":[]},{"id":"1","name":"Container 1","renamed":"true","widgets":[]},{"id":"3","name":"Container 3","renamed":"true","widgets":[]}]
```

in [mockapi](http://5a2144503fd2f10012d78779.mockapi.io/container)

My ts file:

```
updateLocationContainer(){
    /* loop delete all json */
    /* this.containers is Json */
    for (let i = 0; i < this.containers.length; i++) {
        this.containerService.delete(this.containers[i].id).subscribe(result => {},(response: Response) => {
            if (response.status === 500) {
                this.error = 'errorHasOcurred';
            }
        });     
    } /*end for*/

    this.containerService.createContainer(this.containers).subscribe(result => {
        return this.containerService.getContainer().subscribe(res => this.containers = res);
    },(response: Response) => {
        if (response.status === 500) {
            this.error = 'errorHasOcurred';
        }
    });
} /*end func */
```

My service:

```
delete(id){
    const url = `${this.containerUrl}/${id}`;
    return this.http.delete(url,{headers: this.headers})
    .map(response => {
        return response;
    }).catch(error => this.handleError(error));
}
createContainer(container) {
    return this.http.post(this.containerUrl,JSON.stringify(container),{headers: this.headers})
    .map(response => {
        return response;
    }).catch(error => this.handleError(error));
}
```

Comment: How are you determine what indexes should be swapped? You just want to swap index 0 with index 1?

Comment: LLai: yes, I want to swap index 0 with index 1 and update to json api

Answer (score 0):

What if you do a function, with a for cícle, like this:

```
for(let i = 1; i < this.containers.length; i++){
    this.containers.find(x => x.id == i).id = i++;
    this.containers.find(x => x.id == i).renamed = true;
}
```

?

Comment: i dont understand your function, that's not answer for my question

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to swap two elements, you can for example store the object with index `0` temporarily in a variable, overwrite the object in the array with the object in index `1` and then set the object stored temporarily in the index `1`:

```
data = [
         {"id":"1","name":"Container 1","widgets":[]},
         {"id":"2","name":"Container 2","widgets":[]},
         {"id":"3","name":"Container 3","widgets":[]}
       ]

// ...

let temp = this.data[0];
this.data[0] = this.data[1];
this.data[1] = temp;
```